# add / show N more comments. Count is incorrect when direct linking to a comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, mobile-web

I've gone through the other similar posts and can't find exact issue:

**Issue**: A post with N comments will appropriately show "add / show N more comments" when reading the post & no comments are shown. BUT, it will show the same text when you click a link that navigates directly to a comment (i.e. from the inbox). So N comments are already shown (as if you clicked the "add / show" link already), and it still says "add / show N more comments" even though all N are showing.

**Reproduce** (on mobile): Click on any comment response from the top-right arrow dropdown to see. Can upload a screen cap if needed. I've reproduced this on answers with 7 and 10 comments, but but not 4 or less.

For me [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660293/observables-in-angularjs/20660479?noredirect=1#comment30933872_20660479) on mobile shows me "add / show 5 more comments" even though all 10 are comments showing. Clicking the "add / show" link shows me the comment dialog and still shows 10 comments. So in this case, the comment count appears incorrect as well.

Comment: Is this just an issue where visiting a direct link to a comment will expand the comments section as if the "show N more comments" link had been clicked, but it will still say "show N more comments" anyway? (your expression of the issue is a bit unclear)

Comment: in my experience, it only does this when there's enough comments that some are hidden and it _would_ show the "show N more comments" thing (and the link is a link to one of the hidden comments).

Comment: In my scenario, all 7 comments are showing and it says "add /show 7 more comments". Now for this particular post, where there are 4 comments. Clicking on your message takes me to the post, with 4 comments showing, and it's appropriately showing simply "add comment". So currently appears to be a bug for only a certain number of posts. I though I've seen this more than once though (more than just my current issue in the case of 7 comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example link you provide doesn't show the "show N more comments" link anymore - I'll assume it's been fixed since you posted this.